# Swift SpriteKit Setting up collisions/contact bitmasks with 3 nodes

Tags: swift, collision, contacts

I have several collisions set up working perfectly in my app however I cannot for the life of me get the final 2 collisions to work on the same node.

Here is what I have:

```
alien.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.object.rawValue
alien.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.object.rawValue | ColliderType.torp.rawValue
alien.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.object.rawValue

ship.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.ship.rawValue | ColliderType.object.rawValue
ship.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.ship.rawValue
ship.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.ship.rawValue


torpedoNode.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.torp.rawValue
torpedoNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.torp.rawValue
torpedoNode.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.torp.rawValue
```

As the code is above, the torp contacts with the alien. However, the ship does not contact the alien.

If I remove "ColliderType.torp.rawValue" from the alien categoryBitMask then the ship DOES contact the alien but then the torp DOESN'T contact the ship.

For the ship to contact alien I use:

```
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.object.rawValue || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.object.rawValue
```

And for the torp to contact the alien I use:

```
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.torp.rawValue || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.torp.rawValue {
```

How can I get BOTH to work?! I've spent days and just can't get my head around it.

I can get either to work perfectly just not both together.

Comment: Have you tried changing aliens contact to torp and alien? Also have aliens category bitmask set to object.

Comment: Sorry @sicvayne there was a mistake in the code. For the ship to contact alien it should be "Object" "Object". It has been revised

Comment: As it is above the ship won't contact with alien unless I remove the top from the aliens category. But doing this the torp and alien don't collide.

Comment: Substitute || with && see if that works

Comment: No luck. It seems having 2 category bit masks for the alien is the trouble I just don't know why. I can get them to work separately just not together.

Comment: Alien category = alien, alien collision = none , alien contact = torp | ship. Sorry for the choppy answers but im at work lol.

Comment: Now the ship collides with alien and torp collides with alien. But the only problem is when the torp collides with alien it also triggers the ship collides with alien even when it doesn't?

Comment: Body.A.category == alien && body.b.category == torpedo

Comment: @sicvayne THANK YOU!!!

Comment: My pleasure. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem, in this case @Alex Ingram wanted the alien to collide with both the ship and the torpedo, here is the solution that helped him.

```
alien.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.ship.rawValue | ColliderType.torp.rawValue
alien.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.object.rawValue //Im assuming this is his alien's BitMask
alien.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = none
```

Then, in `didBeginContact` he had to write the following

```
 //alien contacting the torpedo
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.object.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.torp.rawValue{
   //then do the following
   }
 //alien contacting the ship
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.object.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.ship.rawValue{
       //then do the following
       }
```